# How to mock @Viewchild MatInput in angular unit test cases

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am trying to mock viewchild in my angular test cases.

here is my html file

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Date</mat-label>
<input matInput #dateInput [matDatepicker]="picker" 
    (dateChange)="dateChange($event)" readonly>
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<br />

<button (click)= "clear()">Clear</button>
```

ts

```
@ViewChild("toDateInput", { read: MatInput }) dateInput!: MatInput;

clear(){
    this.dateInput.value=''
  }
```

spec file

```
 it("DateChange", () => {
expect(component.dateInput.value).toEqual('');
})
```

This unit test case getting fail and giving the error "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')", when I debug component.dateInput getting undefined. Can anyone help me to pass this unit test case

Comment: I think you need to do `import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';` and then in the `imports` array of the `TestBed.configureTestingModule({ imports: [MatInputModule] ..}).compileComponents();`. This `import` should paint the `matInput` and it should be found by the `ViewChild`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to provide a mock directive of `MatInput`, so `ViewChild` could read it from `toDateInput` element.

You can use [`ng-mocks`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/guides/libraries/angular-material) for that.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  return TestBed
    .configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MockModule(MatInputModule), // <- ng-mocks
        // ...
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
});

// ...

it('tests', () => {
  // works now
  expect(component.dateInput.value).toEqual('');
});
```